# Google Trends: Stitching 90 day periods of daily data together

Tags: time-series, dataset, normalization

Google Trends lets you see the amount of researches made on for a term on google during a set period of time, normalized between 0 and 100 (depending on the highest value in that period). I would like to obtain daily data for terms from 2004 to 2015, but unfortunately, it only lets you download 90 days periods of daily data. I can download every 3-month period for all these years but I can't just merge them together because the first 3-month's "100" value doesn't have the same meaning as every other period's 100 and so on.

Is there a way to bring them all together without knowing the absolute values? I don't mind losing the 0-100 format.

Note that I can obtain weekly data on the whole 2004-2015 period as well as monthly, but I'm not sure how I could gain advantage of this to merge the daily files together. The weekly data would in fact tell me what week is the true 100 during that period but how would I adjust the daily data then?

Comment: if you can get the data with slightly overlapping days (e.g. 90 days overlapping by a day or two with the next 90 days, which overlaps with the next) then you can use the ratio of values in the days in common to scale all the values to a common "100" value (say the first one)